# Old Qualifying Exam Problem topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying for qualifying exam and was struggling with this problem. Thanks for any help!

Is it true that if the 1-point compactifications of two locally compact Hausdorff spaces
$X$, $Y$ are homeomorphic, then X and Y are necessarily homeomorphic? Give a proof
or counterexample, as appropriate.

Comment: Homeomorphic spaces with the conditions as above have isomorphic compactifications.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider $X=[0,1)$ and $Y=[0,1/2)\cup(1/2,1]$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer should be negative. Try to find such the spaces $X, Y$ as finite graphs with some vertices excluded.